# ValueError: too many values to unpack in a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please put some light on why am getting a too many to unpack (ValueError in my for loop).Have tried deb

```
 naislist = [('CONTROL FILE', '0', '0', '0'),
            ('REDO LOG', '0', '0', '0'),
            ('ARCHIVED LOG', '.69', '.59', '3'),
            ('BACKUP PIECE', '46.54', '0', '192'),
            ('IMAGE COPY', '0', '0', '0'),
            ('FLASHBACK LOG', '10.15', '6.31', '82'),
            ('FOREIGN ARCHIVED LOG', '0', '0', '0')]
 print "size of naislist is ",len((naislist))
 heading = ('MAIN MENU', 'LEVELS', 'LEVEL2', 'LEVEL3')

 rearrange = dict(zip((0, 1, 2, 3), (len(str(x)) for x in heading)))

 for tu, x in naislist:
     rearrange.update((i, max(rearrange[i], len(str(el))))  for i, el in enumerate(tu))
     rearrange[4] = max(rearrange[4], len(str(x)))
 forkit = '|'. join('%%-%ss' % rearrange[i] for i in xrange(0, 4))
 print '\n'.join((forkit % heading,
                  '-|-'.join(rearrange[i] * '-' for i in xrange(4)),
                  '\n'.join(forkit % (a, b, c, d) for (a, b, c), d in naislist)))
```

Comment: what the hell are you trying to do here?

Comment: Definitely some confusing programming, and a good reason for not noticing the mismatch for the tuple output.

Answer (score 5):

Because there are four elements to each item in `naislist`, while your loop only specifies two variables (`tu, x`) to unpack them into.

Comment: Daniel thanks.am still figuring out how to change the whole for loop to encompass the four variables as in /**** for tu,x,s,v in naislist:***/ ...would u mind directing me to a example to fully expound or a code snippet..pls

Comment: I like the title, ValueError: too many values to unpack in a tuple, and this answer. A common error that has a simple fix. The error message is clear, however, we sometimes just need  a kick in the butt to realize it is a simple correction.